# Core Audio - Remote IO Based Low-Latency Metronome

Tags: xcode, core-audio, remoteio

I am trying to construct a low-latency metronome using Core Audio.

What I am trying to achieve is using Remote IO, which should give me a timestamp for every packet of audio I produce. Then I want to use that to remember when I started playback and subtracting the current timestamp from the starting timestamp to get the current position. Then I want to use that to generate the audio for the metronome as needed.

After some research, I have found that this would be the best way to create a low-latency metronome. However, attempting its implementation and diving into this framework has been rather daunting. If anyone knows how I could put this together or perhaps even point me to sources where I could gather the information I would need to make it work, I would be most grateful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the packet timestamps, and count samples.  If you position the start of each metronome sound an exact number of samples apart at a known sample rate, the tempo will be sub-millisecond accurate.  Per packet time stamp resolution is much less precise.

Comment: ah fantastic, thanks very much.By the way would you by any chance be able to recommend any resources i could study (books/sites/projects) to really help me grasp this framework more proficiently? I've been going through the 'Learning core audio' book, but i was wondering if someone with more experience like yourself would have any suggestions? i come from an audio engineering background, I'm used to working with digital audio but this is a whole new realm! thanks again

Comment: The "Learning Core Audio" book is an excellent resource.  Here's a much older blog site post: http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

Comment: fantastic, thanks for the insight! Ill keep at it, fair bit of the Core Audio book to still cover.

Comment: Can you point in direction of any sample code using this technique?

Comment: See Apple's MixerHost sample code.  How to count audio samples is basic C programming.  How to modify PCM samples requires some DSP study.

Comment: @hotpaw2 i wanted to know if you do any freelance programming? Im having difficulty finding any that know their way around core audio well. Wasn't sure how to get in touch with you so thought id add a comment here!